# SQL: Series of joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am trying to find out how many comments there are in a question that has been made by the owner of the page (the admin).

tblQuestion: (question table)

```
queID
queUserID
queCompanyID (the owner of the page where questions are asked)
```

tblReplies: (where comments in the question are saved)

```
repQuestionID (queID = parent ID)
repUserID (the user ID who made the comment)
```

tblUsers: (where the users are stored)

```
uID (user ID, autoincrement)
uCompanyID (if this id is the same as a company id, the user is admin of that page)
```

So, I want to know how many reply posts are made by the company owner (a user with uCompanyID the reply posts' parent companyID - queCompanyID).

I tried doing this to get number of posts made by page admin, but does not seem to work:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) tblReplies.repID
FROM tblReplies
JOIN 
    tblQuestions ON tblQuestions.queID = tblReplies.repQuestionID
JOIN 
    tblUsers ON tblQuestions.queCompanyID = tblUsers.uCompanyID
WHERE tblQuestions.queID = 68 AND tblUsers.uCompanyID = 1
```

I really hope there is a ninja out there who can help me, I've spent hours and still nothing.

Thanks!

Comment: Your schema description doesn't seem to be complete. For instance, your tblUsers only has one field and you make no reference to Primary Keys or Foreign Keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work (assuming there is a `userID` on the `tblUsers` table.:

```
SELECT 
    count(*), 
    tblReplies.repID
FROM 
    tblReplies, 
    tblQuestions, 
    tblUsers
WHERE
    tblQuestions.queID = tblReplies.repQuestionID AND
    tblQuestions.queCompanyID = tblUsers.uCompanyID AND
    tblUser.uID = tblReplies.repUserID AND
    tblUsers.uCompanyID = 1 AND 
    tblQuestions.queID = 68 

GROUP BY tblReplies.repID
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I tried this solution but I receive following error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'tblUsers.uCompanyID = 1 AND tblQuestions.queID = 68 GROUP BY tblReplies.r' at line 12. Also, there is a userID called uID as you guessed.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
SELECT  count(*) as num_of_comments
FROM tblQuestion a
INNER JOIN tblReplies  b
    on a.queID = b.repQuestionID
INNER JOIN tblUsers c
    on b.queCompanyID = c.uCompanyID 
where a.queID = 68
    and c.uCompanyID = 1
```

Comment: This solution gave all posts that were added under the parent ID. Here is the code I used: SELECT COUNT( * ) AS num_of_comments
FROM tblQuestions
INNER JOIN tblReplies ON tblQuestions.queID = tblReplies.repQuestionID
INNER JOIN tblUsers ON tblReplies.repCompanyID = tblUsers.uCompanyID
WHERE tblQuestions.queID =68
AND tblUsers.uCompanyID =1

Comment: Thank you! This works like a charm, I'm truly grateful for your terrific help.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total 
FROM tblReplies 
WHERE repQuestionID =68 AND repUserID =1
```